# Add custom tokens in Jinja2 (e.g. %% somevar %%)

Tags: python, flask, syntax, jinja2, template-engine

I'm making a Flask app for local development (on a Mac) of HTML templates that will eventually be served through ASP.NET.

For the purposes of local development, I want a way to replace the contents of .NET-style tokens with some data, meaning that Jinja2 would need to be able to recognize `%% ... %%` tokens in addition to the standard ones: `{{ ... }}`, `<% ... %>`, etc.

Everything I've found online pertains to the inclusion of some new functionality within the **existing** tags (e.g. `{{ my_custom_function | arg1 arg2 }}`)

But what about defining a new pattern for tags altogether? Has anyone done this successfully? And will it require modification to the Jinja2 core?

Comment: You don't specify which framework these templates will be used with (Webforms, MVC, Razor, something else). May I suggest that rather than hacking on Jinja to make it kind-of-sort-of act like ASP.NET you simply install [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and actual use the ASP.NET templating library that will be used in production?  Just a thought.

Comment: It will be used with MVC. My specific goal is to keep the dev environment as light as possible, without installing things like Mono, etc. I ended up writing a Jinja function for including files that are read, line-by-line, and have their tokens replaced by regex before rendering. It's fast, light, and prevented me from needing to run a full-on .NET environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use one set for `block_start_string` and `block_end_string`, as well as one set for `variable_start_string` and `variable_end_string`.

From jinja2/environment.py

```
`block_start_string`
    The string marking the begin of a block.  Defaults to ``'{%'``.

`block_end_string`
    The string marking the end of a block.  Defaults to ``'%}'``.

`variable_start_string`
    The string marking the begin of a print statement.
    Defaults to ``'{{'``.

`variable_end_string`
    The string marking the end of a print statement.  Defaults to
    ``'}}'``.
```

You can override these with environment variables.  Though, I don't think there is a way to have multiple types recognized.  For instance, you can't have `{{` and `<%` both work, but with a little hackery you certainly could.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer maybe an example implementation to change the variable marker:

Add following header to the first line in the jinja2 template file.

```
#jinja2:  variable_start_string: "#{" , variable_end_string: "}#"
```